# how to create a variable that can store object of unrelated classes

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I'm using reflection to call methods of different classes which are unrelated in terms of functionality but related in terms of operation. Hence I have to pass the object of those classes to invoke method, but how do I store the object in the same variable?

```
Method target;
if (handlerType.equals("database")){
    target = DatabaseRequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
} else if (handlerType.equals("document")){
    target = DocumentRequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
} else if (handlerType.equals("dictionary")){
    target = DictionaryRequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Handler not implemented for this call");
}
//Method target = RequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
if (target.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)) {
    target.invoke(requestHandler, args);
} else {
    Object result = target.invoke(requestHandler, args);
    body = ValueSerializer.serialize(result, memory);
}
```

How should I declare requestHandler variable so that I can store the object of DatabaseHandler, DocumentHandler and DictionaryHandler? All these classes are not related to each other, so there is not point of using the inheritance with them. I'm from a Python background so really not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: With those names, I hope they implements a `Handler` interface of some sort (didn't checked the real class) so that you can declare it with that type. You can use an `Object` but this would be messy. Please give us more detail on what you are using (what is those classes)

Comment: Your case seems over complicated. What is before that code? using Object  is the only thing that I can think of now...

Comment: @AxelH, They do implement an empty interface. Consider them more of individual class then and contract bind classes.

Comment: @SirKometa, Can you please elaborate on how to use object. Are you talking about declaring requestHandler as Object variable and then instantiating it ?

Comment: Then replace `MyHandler` in my answer with that common interface ... If they are really suppose to be individual class, then you should not even have to implement a method using those three in a same way with reflection ... reflection should not be used at all ... this is to be used in less than 1% of problems, because it brings MORE problems.

Answer (score 1):

`Method.invoke` accept an `Object` for the instance to use. So you can simply declare an `Object` or (better) a common class/interface if available.

```
MyHandler requestHandler ...
```

or

```
Object requestHandler ....
```

FYI :

You should rethink that logic, I believe you should be able to remove the reflection using a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) or a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) to execute a method reference.

Comment: Sure Axel, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below  way to create the object.

```
Object requestHandler = null;
Method target;
if (handlerType.equals("
    target = DatabaseRequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
    requestHandler = new DatabaseRequestHandler();
} else if (handlerType.equals("document")){
    target = DocumentRequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
    requestHandler = new 
} else if (handlerType.equals("dictionary")){
    target = DictionaryRequestHandler.class.getMethod(method, Args.class);
    requestHandler = new DictionaryRequestHandler();
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Handler not implemented for this call");
}
if (target.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)) {
    target.invoke(requestHandler, args);
} else {
    Object result = target.invoke(requestHandler, args);
    body = ValueSerializer.serialize(result, memory);
}
```

Comment: Don't need to post the code using a solution proposed in an answer, you can simply accept the proposed answer if it helps. The final code (especialy like this) don't really help ;)